# Djb2 hash function by Dan Bernstein : Why use bitwise operator when we can just multiply by 33?

Tags: c, hash, bit-manipulation

In Dan Bernstein's famous Djb2 hash function I see it's preferred to use the bitwise operator, but why use it over a simple multiplication ? Is it faster ?

**(hash << 5) + hash = hash * 33**

```
// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // Djb2 hash function by Dan Bernstein
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while ((c = *word++))
    {
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + tolower(c); /* hash * 33 + c */
    }

    return hash % N;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Does https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234967/speeds-of-multiplication-and-division answer your question?

Comment: You may wanna check your *optimized* asm output, because I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if *both* versions of that calculation in this context ultimately generate identical function code. clang 12.01 and gcc 11.2 will both generate a shift-arithmetic-left 5, and a subsequent add, whether you explicitly do as the shown code specifies *or* just use (hash * 33).

Comment: Any modern compiler will generate the same code for both (godbolt confirms), but that was probably not the case when this algorithm was designed in 1991.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why use bitwise operator when we can just multiply by 33?
> but why use it over a simple multiplication ? Is it faster ?

[BITD](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/back_in_the_day), compilers were not as *smart* and so it *was* often faster. [@that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68810248/djb2-hash-function-by-dan-bernstein-why-use-bitwise-operator-when-we-can-just/68810400#comment121607928_68810248)

Today, code for clarity unless your situation demonstrates otherwise (e.g. using a weak compiler).  A good compiler will emit efficient code either way.

```
hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + tolower(c);
// or
hash = hash * 33u + tolower(c);
```

As this is a hash, either is just as clear.

---

**Pedantic**

If `c < 0`, `islower()` is not so well defined.

Alternative, with some casts to quiet pedantic warnings and perhaps a tad faster *unsigned* code.

```
unsigned hash(const char *word) {
    const unsigned char *uword = (const unsigned char *) word;
    unsigned long hash = 5381u;
    int c;
    while ((c = *uword++)) 
        hash = hash*33u + (unsigned)tolower(c);
    }
    return (unsigned) (hash % N);
}
```